# Why world coordinates of google custom map type depend from tile size

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google map api for creating custom map. For this purpose I override *`google.maps.ImageMapType`*. I want to define the tile size that different from standard (256 pixels). It necessary because I need to my custom map fits size of specific area on the page since google maps zoom does not allow me do it with required accuracy. If we define map with *`zoom=0`* and *`tileSize=256`* then one tile contains all range of world coordinates (-180 - 180 degrees longitude and approximately -85 - 85 degrees latitude). However if we change tile size, for example 128 pixels then we see that world coordinates is mapped on 4 tiles, wherein zoom is not changed (*`zoom=0`*). In documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes) I have not found clear explanation this case. Moreover It looks strange that world coordinates depend from tile size. Did you face with this and what workaround did you find?

Examples

1. *`tileSize=256`*, *`zoom=0`*, https://jsfiddle.net/j9y9zLLs/
2. *`tileSize=128`*, *`zoom=0`*, https://jsfiddle.net/74q8nz9p/2/

Open link in examples and find tile *`(0,0)`*. Click on the corners of tile and in console you will see world coordinates. In first example tile *`(0,0)`* has all range of world coordinates. In second example world coordinates are mapped on *`(0,0);(0,1);(1,0);(1,1)`*.

Comment: Please give a code example

Comment: @eugensunic I have done